# Recode values within group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with lots of individuals (id) that have been asked a question (class) n times. Sometimes their answer is `0` or `99` (which are non answer codes for "refused to answer" and "unknown", respectively), however when asked later they do answer the question.

How can I replace the `0` or `99` within an id?

dummy data:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(
  id=rep(1:10,each=4), 
  class=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,99,0,0,0,1,0,2,2,2,99,99,99,
    1,3,3,3,0,2,2,0,99,99,99,99,99,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))
```

What I would like to get

```
res <- data.table(
  id=rep(1:10,each=4), 
  class=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,
    2,2,2,2,99,99,99,99,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))
```

To visualize the example...

```
> cbind(df, res = res[, !"id"])

    id class res.class
 1:  1     1         1
 2:  1     1         1
 3:  1     1         1
 4:  1     1         1
 5:  2     1         1
 6:  2     1         1
 7:  2     1         1
 8:  2    99         1
 9:  3     0         1
10:  3     0         1
11:  3     0         1
12:  3     1         1
13:  4     0         2
14:  4     2         2
15:  4     2         2
16:  4     2         2
17:  5    99         1
18:  5    99         1
19:  5    99         1
20:  5     1         1
21:  6     3         3
22:  6     3         3
23:  6     3         3
24:  6     0         3
25:  7     2         2
26:  7     2         2
27:  7     0         2
28:  7    99         2
29:  8    99        99
30:  8    99        99
31:  8    99        99
32:  8    99        99
33:  9     1         1
34:  9     1         1
35:  9     1         1
36:  9     1         1
37: 10     0         0
38: 10     0         0
39: 10     0         0
40: 10     0         0
    id class res.class
```

In practice I have ~100,000 individuals that's why I've tagged [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), though I am open to other (faster) suggestions.

Comment: How about this `df[class == 0 | class == 99, class := id]` in `data.table`?

Comment: I don't understand why the redundant rows in the result are desirable. Seems like there is at most one answer per individual, so `unique(df[order(class %in% c(0,99))], by="id")`?

Comment: @Frank ultimately yes, though in practice the data are more complicated as there are some people who legitimately change groups who I would like to examine and removing the refuse/unknown noise is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table`, this can also be solved by *updating while joining* with a lookup table for each `id` which replaces all `class` values in `df` by the corresponding value of the lookup table.

The lookup table is created by

```
unique(df[!class %in% c(0,99)], by="id")
```

> ```
>    id class
> 1:  1     1
> 2:  2     1
> 3:  3     1
> 4:  4     2
> 5:  5     1
> 6:  6     3
> 7:  7     2
> 8:  9     1
> ```

The lookup table contains only entries for `id`s with at least one valid answer. In the subsequent *update join* the other `id`s without any valid answer at all are left untouched.

```
df[unique(df[!class %in% c(0,99)], by="id"), on = "id", class := i.class][]
```

> ```
>     id class
>  1:  1     1
>  2:  1     1
>  3:  1     1
>  4:  1     1
>  5:  2     1
>  6:  2     1
>  7:  2     1
>  8:  2     1
>  9:  3     1
> 10:  3     1
> 11:  3     1
> 12:  3     1
> 13:  4     2
> 14:  4     2
> 15:  4     2
> 16:  4     2
> 17:  5     1
> 18:  5     1
> 19:  5     1
> 20:  5     1
> 21:  6     3
> 22:  6     3
> 23:  6     3
> 24:  6     3
> 25:  7     2
> 26:  7     2
> 27:  7     2
> 28:  7     2
> 29:  8    99
> 30:  8    99
> 31:  8    99
> 32:  8    99
> 33:  9     1
> 34:  9     1
> 35:  9     1
> 36:  9     1
> 37: 10     0
> 38: 10     0
> 39: 10     0
> 40: 10     0
>     id class
> ```

```
# check result
all.equal(df$class, res$class)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple two-step solution with `data.table`.

```
df[, class2 := min(class[class != 0 & class != 99]), by = id] # take the minimun value per group, excluding 0 and 99
df[, class_final := ifelse(is.infinite(class2), class, class2)] # take original value when is.infinite returns TRUE i.e. group with 0 or 99 only

all(df2$class == df$class_final) # check now
```

Answer (score 0):

Rcpp solution:

```
df <- data.table(id=rep(1:10,each=4), class=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,99,0,0,0,1,0,2,2,2,99,99,99,1,3,3,3,0,2,2,0,99,99,99,99,99,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))

cppFunction('std::vector<int> remap_class(std::vector<int> id, std::vector<int> df_class) {
  std::map<int, int> class_remap;
  for(int i=1; i<id.size(); i++) {
    if(df_class[i] != 0 & df_class[i] != 99) {
      class_remap[id[i]] = df_class[i];
    }
  }
  for(int i=1; i<id.size(); i++) {
    if(class_remap.count(id[i]) != 0) {
        df_class[i] = class_remap[id[i]];
      }
  }
  return(df_class);
}')

df$class <- remap_class(df$id, df$class)
```

Now check answer is the same.

The answer you posted:

```
df2 <- data.table(id=rep(1:10,each=4), class=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,99,99,99,99,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)) 

all(df2$class == df$class)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` + `tidyr` solution :

```
library(dplyr) # for mutate, group_by and `%>%`
library(tidyr) # for fill
df1 %>%
  mutate(class2 = ifelse(class %in% c(0,99),NA,class)) %>% # we define new column with Nas to be able to use fill
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(class2,.direction = "up")   %>% # we fill up and down
  fill(class2,.direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(class2 = ifelse(is.na(class2),class,class2)) # we replace remaining NAs by initial value
```

Comment: Thanks, however for some of the ids I get unexpected results for instance where there is a `0` recorded on all occasions (id=8) I end up with a `1` and the same for `99` (id=10)

Comment: For `id=8` you have only `99`, not `0` as seen in your post. I can't reproduce your issue, can you please confirm/correct your statement ?

Comment: Apologies - you are correct, id 8 has `99` and id 10 has all `0`. 
However It seems like the `group_by(id)` line doesn't seem to work as the `fill` comes from the next possible value that is not `NA`.

Comment: Are you saying it works for your example but not in general ? because I don't see a difference between your desired output and mine.

Comment: Looking at id 10 my desired output is `0,0,0,0` whereas `class2` in your code returns `1,1,1,1`